# Implementing conflicting interfaces

Tags: c#, .net

If two interfaces have the same properties with different types how can I use a class that implments them. Sample Code:

```
internal interface ITest
{
    string WhatEv { get; set; }
}

internal interface ITest2
{
    int WhatEv { get; set; }
}

internal interface ITest3 : ITest, ITest2
{
}

internal class Simple : ITest3
{
    string ITest.WhatEv { get; set; }

    int ITest2.WhatEv { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ITest3 foo = new Simple();
        foo.WhatEv = "asdf";
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the Ambiguous reference error:

[image: Error In VS]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cast `foo` to either `ITest` or `ITest2`.

```
ITest3 foo = new Simple();
((ITest)foo).WhatEv = "asdf";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. Because these are named the same, and has the same parameters there is no way for the compiler to distinguish  between the two. It would be the same as having two functions with the same parameters, but returns a int or string.

```
int WhatEva(string hello)
{
    return 0;
}

string WhatEva(string hello)
{
    return "0";
}
```

This would give a similar error message -- `Already defines a member called 'WhatEva' with the same parameter types`. Since the Compiler has no way of distinguishing between the two.

Because of this you need to provide the compiler with a way to distinguish the two. In this case you need to preemptively cast `WhatEv` to `ITest`.